# Increasing timeout for WCF web service in c#

Tags: c#, wcf

I currently have an application that is calling a web service on a server for searching. We can expect a large amount of data to be returned, so a search to take longer than a minute is routine.

We've been receiving the below error message for such large volume searches:

> The request channel timed out while waiting for a reply after 00:00:59.7350618. Increase the timeout value passed to the call to Request or increase the SendTimeout value on the Binding. The time allotted to this operation may have been a portion of a longer timeout.

This is something that we've seen asked in multiple questions already posted on StackOverflow, unfortunately none of the available solutions have helped me fix the issue or even be able to configure the time out window.

We've both changed the app.config for the client, increased all the timeouts involved there (CloseTimeout, OpenTimeout, ReceiveTimeout, and SendTimeout) and all web.config values for the service on the server (closeTimeout, openTimeout, and SendTimeout).

None of these changes have had any effect, I still receive the minute timeout.  Any idea why changes to these values would have no effect?

In the examples below, we lowered the time to keep us from having to wait for the full minute during testing.

Web.config:

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <compilation targetFramework="4.0" />
  </system.web>
  <system.diagnostics>
    <trace autoflush="true" />
    <sources>
      <source name="System.Net">
        <listeners>
          <add name="TraceFile" />
        </listeners>
      </source>
      <source name="System.Net.Sockets">
        <listeners>
          <add name="TraceFile" />
        </listeners>
      </source>
    </sources>
    <sharedListeners>
      <add name="TraceFile" type="System.Diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener"
           initializeData="trace.log" />
    </sharedListeners>
    <switches>
      <add name="System.Net" value="Verbose" />
      <add name="System.Net.Sockets" value="Verbose" />
    </switches>
  </system.diagnostics>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <diagnostics>
      <messageLogging logMalformedMessages="false" logMessagesAtServiceLevel="false"
                      logMessagesAtTransportLevel="false" />
    </diagnostics>
    <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="SearchIndexServiceBehavior" name="SearchIndex.Service">
        <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="ISearchIndexServices" />
        <host>
          <timeouts closeTimeout="00:00:10" />
        </host>
      </service>
    </services>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding closeTimeout="00:00:10" openTimeout="00:00:15" sendTimeout="00:00:20"
                 receiveTimeout="00:00:25" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647"
                 maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
                        maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647"
                        maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="SearchIndexServiceBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="false" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.transactions>
    <defaultSettings timeout="00:05:00" />
  </system.transactions>
</configuration>
```

app.config

```
<configuration>
  <configSections>
  </configSections>
  <startup>
  </startup>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_ISearchIndexServices" closeTimeout="00:00:10" openTimeout="00:00:15" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:00:20" allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" maxBufferSize="5242880" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="5242880" messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered" useDefaultWebProxy="true"> 
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="5242880"maxArrayLength="16384" maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
          <security mode="None">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None" realm="" />
            <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="http://MyServer/SearchIndexService/SearchIndexServices.svc" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_ISearchIndexServices" contract="WFC.ISearchIndexServices" name="BasicHttpBinding_ISearchIndexServices" />
    </client>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Comment: How are you connecting to your WCF service?  Are you using a generated client(Add Service Reference), ChannelFactory<T>, or implementing ClientBase<T>?

Comment: The problem description [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wcf/thread/692f5631-c40c-40d7-9a98-8d0d7eb0994b/) may by indicator that your `maxReceivedMessageSize` is perhaps too small. Although then the error message would be rather weird. But i can remember having had that issue too some time ago.

Comment: I just added a Service reference to MyServer

Answer (score 24):

I think you are probably hitting the OperationTimeout for the client side request channel, which for some reason is not easily adjusted via the standard configuration attributes.

Try this in the client code before calling the long-running operation:

```
((IContextChannel)clientProxy.InnerChannel).OperationTimeout = new TimeSpan(0,30,0); // For 30 minute timeout - adjust as necessary
```

where `clientProxy` is an instance of the service-reference-generated Client class (which is derived from `ClientBase<ISearchIndexService>`).

Comment: For anyone else coming here, the InnerChannel property for my service client implemented IClientChannel which has the same OperationTimeout setting. I ended up with just `myClient.InnerChannel.OperationTimeout = new TimeSpan(0,30,0);`. Didn't look up why.

Answer (score 6):

You can try this

```
 SeriveClient client=new ServiceClient();
    var time = new TimeSpan(0, 3, 0);
    client.Endpoint.Binding.CloseTimeout = time;
                client.Endpoint.Binding.OpenTimeout = time;
                client.Endpoint.Binding.ReceiveTimeout = time;
                client.Endpoint.Binding.SendTimeout = time;
```

Comment: OP says he's already tried that, to no effect. That's because it is a different timeout, the OperationTimeout, which is being triggered.

Comment: This answer is usefull, because it shows a different way to access timeouts of the WCF Client, without using app.config.  In my case, it helps me because  I only wanted to TEST my WebService quickly [so having a timeout of 5 secondes].  then, once I know the WebService is working,

Comment: @ChrisDickson, years later, at [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/configuring-timeout-values-on-a-binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/configuring-timeout-values-on-a-binding), Microsoft asserts: "On the client side: SendTimeout – used to initialize the OperationTimeout, which governs the whole process of sending a message, including receiving a reply message for a request/reply service operation."

Answer (score 5):

This Service Model example shows the binding element timeout properties that needed to be set in the client web.config.

Notice that all of the timeout properties are set to 10 minutes. This example uses a **binding configuration** element to set the **"maxItemsInObjectGraph"** property. Usually if you need to turn the timeout up, that means you are probably transferring large amounts of data. Notice also that the sizes of the data to be transferrred are all set to handle up to 2 gigabytes.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<system.serviceModel>
   <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
         <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_ISearchIndexServices" closeTimeout="00:10:00" openTimeout="00:10:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:10:00" allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered" useDefaultWebProxy="true">
            <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
            <security mode="None">
               <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None" realm="" />
               <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
            </security>
         </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
   </bindings>
   <client>
      <endpoint address="http://MyServer/SearchIndexService/SearchIndexServices.svc" behaviorConfiguration="SearchIndexServicesBehavior" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_ISearchIndexServices" contract="WFC.ISearchIndexServices" name="BasicHttpBinding_ISearchIndexServices" />
   </client>
   <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
         <behavior name="SearchIndexServicesBehavior">
            <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647" />
         </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
   </behaviors>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Answer (score 0):

The timeout is the send timeout on the client. This is how long the client is prepared to wait for a response and so has to be set on the client rather than the service

Comment: The SendTimeout on the clients app.config is set to 20 seconds. Even with it set that low, the request still take a minute to error. I have the sendTimeout on both the client and service set to 20 seconds.

Comment: It sounds as if your config setting isn't getting picked up - have you checked in the debugger whether the client proxy's binding is definitely 20s?

Comment: The SendTimeout only covers the time to completion of the transport protocol for delivery of the request message to the server. If the Response message then takes a long time coming, this timeout is not triggered.

Answer (score 0):

Timeouts are a pain in debugging. Who can debug in under a minute!  I used Junior M/BuzzWilder from above and added the following to the service call in the app.config:

```
            <binding name="WSHttpBinding_bindingname"
                     openTimeout="01:00:00"
                     closeTimeout="01:00:00"
                     receiveTimeout="01:00:00"
                     sendTimeout="01:00:00"
                     >
```

Good bye service time outs. :)

Answer (score 0):

As of now, more and more WCF users are moving into ASP.Net Core , so  I added also a guide here how to increase timeouts using CoreWCF, although the approach should also work with WCF.

Here is how you can test out and configure timeouts in WCF more easily. The timeouts are configured in the client project.

First off, Image proof or it did not happen. Here you see that I get a timeout after already 15 seconds so how did I do that ?

[image: Quick timeout for WCF client]

Note, I use the following Nuget packages for the client, which is a .NET 6 console application:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="System.ServiceModel.Duplex" Version="4.10.*" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.ServiceModel.Federation" Version="4.10.*" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.ServiceModel.Http" Version="4.10.*" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.ServiceModel.NetTcp" Version="4.10.*" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.ServiceModel.Security" Version="4.10.*" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

The server project uses these Nuget packages, I have made  client and service WCF from the CoreWCF templates :

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="CoreWCF.Primitives" Version="1.*" />
    <PackageReference Include="CoreWCF.Http" Version="1.*" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

Inside Reference.cs, the auto-generated file on the client we got this method:

```
   [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("Microsoft.Tools.ServiceModel.Svcutil", "2.1.0")]
    public partial class ServiceClient : System.ServiceModel.ClientBase<MyService.IService>, MyService.IService
    {
        
        /// <summary>
        /// Implement this partial method to configure the service endpoint.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="serviceEndpoint">The endpoint to configure</param>
        /// <param name="clientCredentials">The client credentials</param>
        static partial void ConfigureEndpoint(System.ServiceModel.Description.ServiceEndpoint serviceEndpoint, System.ServiceModel.Description.ClientCredentials clientCredentials);

//more code
```

We make note of the namespace of the client and add the following partial class with a configured set of timeouts. Adjust as desired these timeouts.

I add a file called ServiceClient here, the class name matches the ServiceClient class name in the Reference.cs also.

```
namespace MyService
{
    public partial class ServiceClient
    {

        /// <summary>
        /// Implement this partial method to configure the service endpoint.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="serviceEndpoint">The endpoint to configure</param>
        /// <param name="clientCredentials">The client credentials</param>
        static partial void ConfigureEndpoint(System.ServiceModel.Description.ServiceEndpoint serviceEndpoint, System.ServiceModel.Description.ClientCredentials clientCredentials)
        {
            serviceEndpoint.Binding.OpenTimeout 
                = serviceEndpoint.Binding.CloseTimeout
                = serviceEndpoint.Binding.ReceiveTimeout
                = serviceEndpoint.Binding.SendTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15);
        }

    }
}
```

Timeouts set here is set to 15 seconds. Obviously, you would like to have these timeouts perhaps a bit longer, I only entered a small value to quickly test it. Default values are usually either 30 or 60 seconds, in production you might consider many minutes in case your servicemethods should perform long running jobs - or consider a framework for this such as Hangfire instead.

The benefit of this approach is that if you update Reference.cs (which is still a bit cumbersome in VS 2022, not as easy as in ye ole days with WCF in .NET Frmaework), your configured settings are still kept. By setting the endpoint binding you can do a lot of other configuration too.